# When to use a java singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I understand that a singleton class will only have one instance per jvm.

But from a design point of view, how to know when to make a class a singleton? I understand that a utility class maybe a good example of a singleton, but what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to enforce singleton behaviour for objects that don't make sense to have more than one instance within your application. For example, wouldn't make much sense for any application to have two *SecurityManager* s.

At times having two or more instances could break an application specially *system* software. A good example would be an Anti-Virus application. Imagine having two instances of the *real-time monitoring* component each flagging one another as a rogue process.

How about an *Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)*? Wouldn't connect anything if every module received a new instance of the *Bus*. How about having multiple application *cache* instances? You would be wasting resources by fetching something that's already available in some other *cache* instance leading to poor performance.

So, I hope you get the idea. Anything and everything that could lead to undesired application behaviour upon having two or more instances of it is a candidate for becoming a *Singleton*.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use the singleton pattern.  It makes your code harder to test and is basically a fancy global variable.  If you want to have one instance of a class per jvm, design your code so it only creates one instance of a class per jvm.  There's no need to introduce a singleton pattern for that.  For some examples of this, check out Spring and how it uses "singleton".  That's a good way to do it.

Comment: why singleton makes it harder to test?

Comment: Imagine you've got a singleton that connects to a database.  Now you want to test some code that incidentally uses that singleton.  It is very difficult to test that code without connecting to a database.  If the singleton was instead a parameter you passed in, you could very easily mock it out.

Comment: 'singleton' in spring is not a singleton, is just a flyweight .. you can make `new SomeObject()` , so if you want a one single instance in hole application that is not the solution.

Comment: @nachokk it is if you let Spring create your objects for you.  Which is what you should be doing, why else would you be using it for DI?

Comment: it's not the same, cause potential clients can create new instance of that object, you can do some magic change constructor accesibility and that is a little more like a singleton

Comment: @nachokk It can be *functionally* the same if I know that I'm not going to use `new` because I'm already using a DI framework like Spring (or enforce it myself).  The benefits of avoiding the singleton *pattern* are worth it, in my experience.

Comment: yes  you know what are you using xD , if that application is a client or some other programmers works with it.. that's the point .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a singleton only if you know that you will every need at most 1 instance of the object.

For example,

> A logger: It's very unlikely that you need two loggers.
>
> A class that accesses resources of a specific type.
>
> Some types of factories (read more about the factory pattern for more details)

Note that the examples above are general guidelines and there are **definitely** exceptions.

This is a really good place to learn more about singletons: http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

My advice to new programmers is to very, very seldomly use the singleton pattern.  I've never seen anyone underuse the singleton pattern, but I see people abuse it ALL the time.

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

How and when to use Singleton classes

http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2008/04/20/how-and-when-to-use-singleton-classes/

examples from above link

what are the uses of a Singleton?.

Singleton classes are normally used for things such as a Factory classes, Builder classes and things like that. A few real world examples include the the SessionFactory class in Hibernate – it’s actually a singleton. Or with log4j, when you call its logger, it uses a singleton class to return it. If anyone has used Cairngorm within Flex/Actionscript 3, its model locator is a Singleton.